# Symfony2 - why the integer value in the hidden field is not recognized as integer?

Tags: forms, symfony, hidden-field

I have a custom form type for a "**Rating**" entity in my Symfony2 project. It has a **value** field, that is *integer*. Then, I created the form for this entity. Here follows the code:

```
class RatingType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options){
     $builder->add('value', 'hidden', array('data' => 113));
  }

  public function getDefaultOptions(array $options){
     return array(
         'data_class' => 'Acme\ArticleBundle\Entity\Rating',
     );
  }    

  public function getName() {
     return 'spesax_productbundle_pratingtype';
  }
}
```

When I press the **submit** button in my html page, the form is not validated and a "**not an integer**" error message is displayed on the screen!
Why Symfony2 doesn't cast the value **113** to integer?
What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Does it validate with an integer field type? (`$builder->add('value', 'integer'...`)

Comment: I thought so but I had to ask. I was trying to find a way to set the field type to both `hidden` and `integer` with no success. How do you validate the form? Did you try with [Type constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Type.html)?

Comment: No, I use assertions just inside the entity PHP class.... However, I think that the problem inside the entity `Rating`, since the field `value` is mapped as an `integer`. Therefore, Symfony2 automatically validates the value provided by the hidden field of the rendered form, and with no-reason states that it is not an integer!

Comment: I guess you check for the type using type="integer"? Try using "numeric" instead. As symfony has no way of telling if the hidden field should be an integer or string it doesn't do a typecast. Integer fails as "113" is not an integer in PHP. On the other hand, numberic checks if a string can be casted to integer correct, which is the case, so this should validate correctly.

Comment: @Sgoettschkes Great! You are right! Post the answer, I will vote and accept it! Danke

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using the type `hidden` instead of `integer` in your FormType, symfony does not know what to expect from the field, so it assumes a string. When binding the form to the entity, the hidden field gets stored into the entity field as a string.

Validating the entity fails if you validate with `type="integer"`, as the value is not an integer but a string which could be casted to an integer (Saving it will work because doctrine looks if it can convert to the given type).

**The trick is to use `type="numeric`" in your entity validation annotation.** This will check if the field can be transformed into an integer, not if the value is a real integer right now.

Comment: This also applies if a form-field is defined as type `integer`, but has the option `disabled=true` ...

Comment: Does `numeric` allow decimal places? How do I specify in one annotation that it should allow decimal places (because it’s actually a `float`), but in another that it shouldn’t (because it’s actually an `integer`)?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Sgoettschkes answer this worked for me. Here is an example:

```
/**
* @var integer
* @Assert\NotBlank()
* @Assert\Type(type="numeric")
*
* @ORM\Column(name="value", type="integer",  nullable=false)
*/

private $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to typecast the entity's parameter in its *set* method. For example:

```
/** @var integer $value */
private $value;

public function setValue($val){
     $this->$val = (int) $val;
     return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beltouche's answer worked for me: By typecasting it to an integer in the entity it saved a database update when otherwise doctrine considered the fields as non-matching.

Because 12345 !== '12345' i was seeing an unnecessary update for my $id field even if nothing else in the form/entity was changing.

```
/** @param int $id */
private $id;

public function setId($id){
    $this->$id = (int) $id;
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use next:

```
$builder->add('fieldname', 'integer', array('attr' => array('style' => 'display: none') ) )
```

Comment: Although this is a neat trick, it is a Separation of Concerns violation: you shouldn't control view state from PHP code.